# Analysis method for nominal dichotomous data from mixed design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, frequency, categorical-data

I have the following data set (example):

```
Subject Treatment-group Decision_x  Decision_y  Decision_z
      1               1     A           B           A
      2               1     B           B           B
      3               1     B           B           A
      4               2     B           B           B
      5               2     A           A           A
      6               2     A           B           B
```

In other words, a participant (`Subject`) was part of an independent `Treatment-group` (IV, between subjects, df=1) and decided multiple times for either A or B (DV, df=1, repeated-measures, random order).

I want to find out whether subjects in group 1 show a different decision pattern compared to those in group 2, e.g. because they vote for option B significantly  more often.

I am looking for a test that tells us about the between-group differences while accounting for all other requirements.

Comment: How are `Decision_x`, `Decision_y` and `Decision_z` related? Is this the "decision pattern" you are talking about? Is there a time interval between those decisions? Could you provide a little bit more detail?

Comment: There is a time interval between the decisions (albeit very small). The problems to base the decisions on are varied slightly (this is kind of an independent variable, but we don't expect effects there since the problems themselves are very very similar). 
For example, I want to be able to say "Subjects in group 1 significantly chose B more/less often across all decisions".